# How to manage developing former Visual Studio solution in Linux?

Tags: linux, visual-studio, visual-c++

*sigh*

In my third try to introducing Linux to my everyday life I'm still bouncing hard on programming.

I have solution for my major thesis' program created in Visual Studio (five projects in one solution; 4 static libs, one executable), and managed with it since it's beginning. It's posted on Git, so I thought, that I'll try changing it and compiling on my laptop with Ubuntu 18.4. While changing it was no-effort task (Linux text editors are neat; as opposed to almost non-existent IDEs), compiling in the other hand was the point I doubted in all my skills.

First problem I've encountered is that I have no idea how to manage multiple projects outside VS. I mean, there are .vcxproj files with data, but not very useful for what I saw.

Second problem are references - I have no idea how to link #include directories to specific point in files without going `../MainFolder/subfolder/file.h` which is extremely unesthetic.

I expect, that those are just iceberg's peaks, and I will encounter massive amount of problems in future, but as for now - can anybody give me idea of how to manage such project in Linux?

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/linux-development-with-c-in-visual-studio/ Microsoft still wants you to use Windows/VS as your primary environment, while Linux is just a remote server.

Comment: Not good, tbh. But it will run if I will compile source files, won't it?